# Zoom in on maker group in leaflet mapbox?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I have a `layerGroup` in my map which has a lot of markers and another `layerGroup` which has a lot of circles. I need to zoom in on these layer groups but I cannot find the exact API method to do so.

I have tried:

```
var myLayerGroup = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);
myLayerGroup.fitBounds(); // tried this
myLayerGroup.setBounds(); // and this too
```

I am not sure which method in the API will work for me. How to zoom in on a layer of markers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch from using layerGroup to featureGroup, theb you can use `getBounds()` on a feature group to retrieve its bounds, then use `map.fitBounds(result)` to zoom to that view.

Comment: Console error says `TypeError: myLayerGroup.getBounds is not a function`

Comment: Ah sorry. Make sure to use a `featureGroup` instead of a `layerGroup`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30028863/setbounds-to-two-different-featuregroups-at-once-mapbox-leaflet Any idea about this?