# setBounds to two different featureGroups at once mapbox leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I am working on a map where I have two feature layers.

```
var myFeatureGroup1 = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);
var myFeatureGroup2 = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);
```

I am setting bounds like:

```
map.fitBounds(myFeatureGroup1.getBounds());
map.fitBounds(myFeatureGroup2.getBounds());
```

But for obvious reasons, myFeatureGroup2 is set bounds on. Is ther a way by which I can fit bounds to multiple layerGroups? Like both of them at once? Is there a way I can merge them into a third layerGroup and fit bounds on it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
map.fitBounds(myFeatureGroup1.getBounds().extend(myFeatureGroup2.getBounds()));
```

See the [LatLngBounds](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlngbounds-extend) documentation, this is the first documented method.

Answer (score 1):

How about using [TurfJS](http://turfjs.org/static/docs/module-turf_merge.html) to `merge` the two bounds together(convert them to geoJSON) first, then `map.fitBounds(result)`.

Comment: the answer from @tmcw is the better + simpler option.